# Disable Restlet loggings

Tags: tomcat, restlet, restlet-2.0, catalina.out

How to disable Restlet loggings to catalina.out, I tried to set Logger "org.restlet" level to SEVERE in RestletApplication but it didn't work.

```
static {
    // Install logging bridge (JUL -> LOG4J)
    SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("org.restlet");
    for (Handler handler : logger.getParent().getHandlers()) {
        // Find the console handler
        if (handler.getClass().equals(java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.class)) {
            handler.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by configuring logging.properties file either at JDK level, tomcat level or even at the webapp level.

Increasing ConsoleHandler level in logging.properties to other than the default INFO level will disable restlet logs.

Regards.